# A function that mapsclosed sets to closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

We have: $f: A \to B$ where $A$ and $B$ are both closed subsets of $\Bbb R$. Is f necessarily continuous?

I know a few things here:

If we took $[a,b] \in A$ and $[c,d]$ in $B$. Then we have $f([a,b]) = [c,d]$ makes $f$ closed and bounded since $A$ will emit some finite subcover, a collection of the covers on all the points. But just because $f$ is closed and bounded does not mean its continuous and furthermore what if $U = [c,d] \cup [e,f]$, and $f([a,b])= U$. I can't see how that could be continuous with $\forall ~\epsilon>0~ \exists~\delta>0$ such that $\mid x−a|<~\delta~⇒|f(x)−f(a)|<\epsilon$ as our definition of continuity.

Comment: I think you have a misconception on closed functions. A function is called closed if the image of every closed subset is closed. In your case, we only know that the image of one closed subset is closed, namely $A$ (assuming $f$ is surjective. Otherwise that might not be true either)

Comment: I think that is closed and bounded because it can be shown to be compact. @G.Chiusole

Comment: You are talking about two different concepts. The sets $A$ and $B$ are closed (by assumption). However, this has nothing to do with the function itself. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps)

Comment: Ah you're correct. It simply means that the image, in this case $[c,d]$ is closed and compact, correct? I think I read my notes wrong lol.@G.Chiusole

Comment: You mean that if a function is closed, then its image is closed and compact? That is not the case. The identity function $(0,1) \rightarrow (0,1)$ is a closed function, but its image $(0,1)$ is not closed.

Comment: No what I meant was that if a function is continuous and $A \in \Bbb R$, and is closed and bounded,$ f(A)$ is closed and bounded.@G.Chiusole

Comment: Essentially continuity preserves closed and boundedness (aka compactness). @G.Chiusole

Comment: Yes. The continuous image of a compact set is compact. The converse is not true though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Take $f(x)=1$ if $x=0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x \neq 0$  on the real line.

Then $f(\Bbb{R})=\{0,1\}$  which is closed but $f$ is not continuous.

Or you can define the same function on  $[0,1]$ and again $f([0,1])=\{0,1\}$

Comment: Ah thnx lol can't believe I missed this counterexample.

Comment: You are welcome..:)